# PDF Python Linux environment

Tags: python, linux, flask, docx2pdf

I am trying to create a **flask app** that creates text documents and then covert them into a PDF.

Currently, I use these python libraries: **Docx** (for creating Word documents) and **Docx2pdf** (for PDF converting). The code works when I use it on my local machine (**Windows**) but it does not work when I use attempt to deploy it on a **Linux** server returns this error ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none).

I suspect that Linux can't work with Docx2pdf library.

Could you confirm if my suspicious is true?

Also, can you suggest any PDF converter library working on a Linux environment?

Thanks

Comment: pypi says only windows and macos are supported [docx2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/)

Comment: LibreOffice is able to efficiently do this as a CLI - in any environment where it i available.